# Get div content and then modify it

Tags: jquery, html

The scenario is, I want to get a div content and then  modify it in order to insert it in another div.
Code below :

```
$("#loupe").live("click",function(){
    $('#divBody').empty();
    $('#divTitle').empty();
    var title = $(this).closest('div').find('.stepTitle').text();
    var divContent = $(this).closest('div').html();
    // code to modify the content to be inserted in the modal 
    $('#divBody').append(divContent);
    $('#divTitle').append(title);
    $('#div').modal({ dynamic: true });
});
```

more in detail , the first div contains a title that i want to remove before inserting content into the new div , so the new div must contains content without title

```
<div>
    <h4 class="StepTitle">Planing des congés pour le service de <%=service.getNomService() %> au <%=month%> / <%=year%>   
        <span style="float: right;">
            <i class="icon-white icon-search" style="cursor: pointer;" id="loupe"> </i>  
            <i class="icon-white  icon-remove" style="cursor: pointer;" onclick="$(this).closest('div').remove();"> </i> 
        </span>  </h4>  
    <table border="1" style="border-color: gray;">
    </table> 
</div>
```

//**********************the div into which content will be inserted

```
<div id="div" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog"
        aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h3 id="divTitle">
            //here the title
        </h3>

    </div>
    <div id="divBody" class="modal-body">
        here the other content
    </div>
    <div  class="modal-footer">
        <input type="button" class="btn" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" value="fermer">
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: So, what's the problem?

Comment: other than the casing on stepTitle in jquery compared to the html that is.

Comment: once i get the content , i want to remove some element from this content

Comment: Then don't append the title? I have to admit I'm a little confused here. Your code appends a title then your question says how do I not append the title? #divTitle.append('')

Comment: yes i want to append the title separetly

Comment: see edited comment, just leave the divTitle.append empty

Comment: the title will be appended into a div , and the core of the div to another div

Comment: `#divBody`,`#divTitle`,`.stepTitle` - I don't see ANY of these in your markup.

Comment: i added the code remaining

Comment: i managed to get this with , var divContent = $(this).closest('div').find('table').clone();

Comment: .clone() is the solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

jQuery allows you to work with fragments of a page (as well as XML).

Once you've used the `.html` method to assign the HTML of an element to a variable, you can operate on the HTML like so:

```
var html, withoutTitle;
html = $('#someDiv').html();
withoutTitle = $(html).remove('#title').html();
$('#someOtherDiv').html(withoutTitle);
```

I haven't tested this code, so you may need to tweak it a bit to suit your purposes.

Comment: when i teste it , instead of the div content , the is appended to the other div , because remove() methode returns the removed object i think

Comment: I didn't expect this code to work for you exactly as written.  I expect you'll need to make some modification to it to fit your project.